# How to fire another request only after previous one is finished?

Tags: javascript, http, promise, fetch

I am making http requests to the weather service. How do i postpone them until the previous one is completed? I tried making 'const allow=true' switch  to control the state, but somehow the requests keep firing. It should not be done by disabling the button! Just need to prevent requests while 'allow' is false.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/weather?address=' + location)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.error) {
                        messageOne.textContent = data.error
                    } else {
                        messageOne.textContent = data.location
                        messageTwo.textContent = data.forecast
                    }
                }).finally(allow = true)
```

Please, see the full code 
https://jsfiddle.net/pgdf4msa/2/

Comment: `.finally(allow = true)` would never work.  You need to pass a function to `.finally()` as in: `.finally(() => {allow = true})`.  When you don't pass a function, the code is executed immediately.  When you pass a function, you give the promise infrastructure a chance to call the function when it's good and ready to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried moving 'allow = true' from 'finally' block to 'then'

```
.then((data) => {
                    if (data.error) {
                        messageOne.textContent = data.error
                    } else {
                        messageOne.textContent = data.location
                        messageTwo.textContent = data.forecast
                        allow = true
                    }
                })
```

It seems finally block was executed before the request has done pending.

Comment: This will never set `allow = true` if `fetch()` rejects its promise.  Much better to do it in `.finally()` like you originally tried, but to put it in a callback function like I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
.finally(allow = true)
```

would never work because you need to pass a function to `.finally()` as in:

```
.finally(() => {allow = true})
```

When you don't pass a function, the code is executed immediately, not later when the promise is done.  When you pass a function, you give the promise infrastructure a chance to call the function when it's ready to call the function (sometime later).